# Battery only charges to 85 after 2 weeks

Tags: laptop, battery

I'be been continuously using my new laptop HP 250 G2 for two weeks (always connected to the AC wall). The status was always fully charged. Yesterday I decided to run it on batteries until the power was 15%-20% and now it doesn't charge to full as it did before . It stops at 34Wh , 85%.

What can be the issue? I'm running ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Look at the BIOS. There are laptops that limits the full charge of the battery in order "to enhance the lifetime of batteries" (I am personally not convinced at all, but well). 85% is what they normally reach; it is a kind of "battery life extender" option in BIOS.

Comment: Why wasn't that battery limiter activated the first 2 weeks that I've used the laptop?

Comment: No idea... ¿was it that? Maybe the BIOS will permit a couple of full cycles before limiting. Mind you, all this battery things are a bit like voodoo to me (and I am an electrical engineer --- I simply think that batteries are disposables, full stop, you have to live with that.)